# Книги по ООА и ООП

Tags: ооп, книги

Сейчас я читаю книгу Шилдта по C# (опыта по программированию не было до этого, сейчас я знакомлюсь с делегатами и событиями) и хочу параллельно начать знакомиться с основами ООА и ООП. Но книг полно по данной теме, прошу определится с выбором что можно почитать для новичка. Вот книги, которые мне пригляделись. Но что взять для начала?

1. Джим Арлоу, Айла Нейштадт. UML 2 и Унифицированный процесс. Практический объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование
2. Буч Г. - Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами приложений
3. Head First - Паттерны проектирования

Comment: Ну кому как удобно я например прочитал книгу про JavaScript и VisualBasic и уже имею представление о ООП! 

Answer (score 2):

Первую не читал, но если выбирать из второй и третьей, то берите третью. Действительно подробно и понятно написано. Может, не слишком формально, но именно с таких книг и удобно начинать. Буч - это первоисточник, а первоисточники всегда читать трудно. Буч об UML, Строуструп о C++, Керниган&Пайк или Хэзфилд о C - такие книги в гораздо большей степени отражают философию языка или подхода и для их понимания на 100% нужно уже быть подкованным с технической точки зрения и иметь опыт.